# Select control and Bootstrap grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm getting a strange issue with bootstrap grid. This is the first time I have this problem, and can't find something releavant on Internet. I have a form with Label and their Select control, each on a `col-md-3` div. The problem i have is that the 4 firsts controls are ok, but the fifth is alignd to the right of the screen, and all the others are ok.... Here's my code and a screenshot :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="select-1">Vérification de l'état</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <select name="select-1">
        <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
        <option value="valid">Validé</option>
        <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="select-2">Nettoyage corps de chauffe</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <select name="select-2">
        <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
        <option value="valid">Validé</option>
        <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="select-3">Démontage et nettoyage du brûleur</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <select name="select-3">
        <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
        <option value="valid">Validé</option>
        <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="select-4">Nettoyage préfiltre (le cas échéant)</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <select name="select-4">
        <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
        <option value="valid">Validé</option>
        <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="select-5">Nettoyage du filtre de la pompe</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <select name="select-5">
        <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
        <option value="valid">Validé</option>
        <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="select-6">Verification des dispositifs de sécurité</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <select name="select-6">
        <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
        <option value="valid">Validé</option>
        <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label class="control-label" for="select-7">Verification du circulateur de chauffage</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <select name="select-7">
        <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
        <option value="valid">Validé</option>
        <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
      </select>
    </div>
```

Screenshot : http://prntscr.com/d21j33

Comment: You really need to start using stackoverflows code snippet.

Comment: I'll prob have a look to that, but for now I have no free time to do it. Thx for the advice. And the problem is I got a lot of CSS, so even on JS Fiddle, this is not releavant..

Comment: Bootstrap grid system is 12 columns wide and you have 5 * 3 = 15 columns so the fifth one overflows onto the next row. Try using col-md-2

Comment: I have much more than 5, I have 14 col-md-3 total on the form, but they should all float left, like the last ones..

Comment: There you go. still I didn't understand your question nor follow your code. Would help if you comment the line where you have the strange behaviour. https://jsfiddle.net/efznx8Lq/

Comment: Yes, i do have the same result on JS Fiddle. And on my own site, when i reduce the window, they all float left properly. The problem is when you're on full wide screen. At this disposition, you can have 4 col-md-3 on the screen at one time. The problem is the 4 firsts are correct, the fifth is alone on second row, float right, and all the others are correct, 4 per row. I don't understand why 5th control is alone on a line, as you can see on my screen capture..

Comment: I assume that you want to rely on bootstrap to put the overflow of columns at the beginning of the next line. I wouldn't do that, instead you should put them in rows, max 12 grid units per row.

Comment: Hm ok, i encapsulated my rows into col-md-12 rows, and that do the trick. Still don't know why I have to do it, I did the same many times, and it always worked, but not this time. Thank you anyway !

Comment: I cannot find the exact css rule that causes this, but I wouldn't bother because it wasn't designed to do this. Just for fun, try assigning width 26% to the label that floats to the right (the bad one) and see what happens.

Comment: Still the same, i guess he's having a bad day and doesn't want to work as i want. Taking him into a row is the solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap isn't supposed to align the overflow of grid (over 12 units) as you want.

Instead use rows to separate each 12 grid units in a line.

I updated your code https://jsfiddle.net/mydkahdf/1/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" for="select-1">Vérification de l'état</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select name="select-1">
      <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
      <option value="valid">Validé</option>
      <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" for="select-2">Nettoyage corps de chauffe</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select name="select-2">
      <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
      <option value="valid">Validé</option>
      <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" for="select-3">Démontage et nettoyage du brûleur</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select name="select-3">
      <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
      <option value="valid">Validé</option>
      <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" for="select-4">Nettoyage préfiltre (le cas échéant)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select name="select-4">
      <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
      <option value="valid">Validé</option>
      <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" for="select-5">Nettoyage du filtre de la pompe</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select name="select-5">
      <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
      <option value="valid">Validé</option>
      <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" for="select-6">Verification des dispositifs de sécurité</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select name="select-6">
      <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
      <option value="valid">Validé</option>
      <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label class="control-label" for="select-7">Verification du circulateur de chauffage</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <select name="select-7">
      <option value="no" selected>Sans objet</option>
      <option value="valid">Validé</option>
      <option value="notvalid">Non validé</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```